# Search box for views and tags

Tags: views, search, taxonomy-terms

I want to be able to have a search box so that when you search, the result is displayed in a view. I want to search for tags in nodes.

The reason I want to display this in views is because I only want to display 3 fields and I want to display it in a 3x3 grid with a pager.

I don't want to be using Apache Solr because the output of the search is quite ugly and I can't customise the fields I want to display etc... Also I want to keep the layout consistent with the rest of my views.

I found this http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views but it requires views 3, and I don't feel comfortable upgrading.

Is there any way to have some sort of search box for views that would search for tags? and what module would you recommend me for tagging my content?

I'm using Drupal 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You create a search box for Views by adding a filter and then setting it to be "exposed". This creates a form by which the user can set filter values such as tags.

You don't need any special module for tagging under normal circumstances as the core Taxonomy module works perfectly well.

Comment: yes it would work. All tags will be shown to you in dropdown or as autocomplete widget with which it will show all matching results

Answer (score 0):

Create view and use **better exposed filter** module to have a search box for the view.

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single-
>   or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively.